# rm -r * in unix

Tags: rm

I am about to enter the command: `rm -r *` in a directory where I would like all files and directories (and their files) removed. My concern is that unix also has the `./` and the `../` directories. `rm -r` should follow all directories: does that mean it will follow `../` and delete stuff in higher up directories? I can't seem to find the answer to this by googling.

Comment: @ChrisDown right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIXly, `*` does not expand to include `.` and `..` (or any filename beginning with a dot) unless you actually explicitly include it using options specific to your shell (eg. `dotglob` in bash).

It's "safe" (unless any of your files start with a dash, in which case you should use `rm -- *`), assuming that's what you mean to do, but you will not delete files with filenames starting with a dot.

Might I suggest that you do this instead:

```
cd .. && rm -r directory
```

Comment: good suggestion, will use that instead.